# Creating a stream out of an httppostedfile always returns an empty file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
file.InputStream.Seek(0,0);
Stream s = file.InputStream
s.Position = 0;
s = File.Create(path);
```

My goal is for the final output to be a duplicate of the original file. Using file.SaveAs(path) successfully does this. However converting it to a stream and then trying to create the file does not. Is there something completely obvious that I'm missing or is there a bigger problem?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this line:

```
s = File.Create(path)
```

That doesn't do what you want it to. That's creating a *new* stream - at which point you're ignoring the old one entirely.

You probably want something like:

```
using (var output = File.Create(path))
{
    file.InputStream.CopyTo(output);
}
```